# How to replicate rows in dataframe for every comma separated item in a column

Tags: r

I have this dataframe called `mydf`. What I need to do is replicate the rows for every item separated by comma in the `cd` column and get the result as shown in `result`.

```
mydf<-structure(list(cc = structure(1:3, .Label = c("a", "b", "c"), class = "factor"), 
    cd = structure(1:3, .Label = c("e,f,g", "f,g,s", "g,h,g"), class = "factor"), 
    individuals = structure(1:3, .Label = c("apple", "ball", 
    "cat"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("cc", "cd", "individuals"
), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")
```

result

```
cc   cd          individuals
a    e           apple
a    f           apple 
a    g           apple 
b    f           ball
b    g           ball
b    s           ball
c    g           cat
c    h           cat 
c    g           cat
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dplyr way

```
library(stringi)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

mydf %>%
  mutate(cd = cd %>% stri_split_fixed(",") ) %>%
  unnest(cd)
```

Comment: Please explain how your answer solves the problem, it will help everyone understand your solution with more clarity and for future reference.